# text field significantly bigger in certain browser

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

I have the below text field in my page:

```
<input class="message" id="message" name="message" type="text" size="65" />
```

For some reason in the latest FireFox for OS X it is about 200pixels wider than it is in the latest Chrome (mac/pc) FireFox(pc) and IE(pc)

Any suggestions on how I can fix this or why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post your CSS.

However, regardless of this, I think your fix is adding this rule

```
    width: 300px; /* change size accordingly */
```

to

```
#message {
```

or

```
.message {
```

and removing the size

```
<input class="message" id="message" name="message" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the dimension via `style` or `class`:

```
<input class="message" id="message" name="message" type="text" style="width:200px;" />
```

Comment: I don't want to down vote or anything because this will work, but if you can you really should do this with a style in your .css file vs. inline.

        .message { width: 300px; }


Like Dan Beam suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers usually render form elements differently(and it also varies by OS). If you want your form elements to look the same then style it with CSS. In this case, just add a width in your css like so:

```
input {
  width: 200px }
}
```

Comment: did you mean `width: 200px;` ?  I also don't recommend using global styles (on *all* tags, like this is).  Also, your avatar is pedobear - I lol'ed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP you can use the Request.ServerVariables("http_user_agent") method to get the browser and OS information and set the variable (that ends up being the size attribute of the message text object) to a smaller size.

Comment: why would you do that?  that makes me sad on the inside, :_(

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have a different way of rendering different elements on your DOM; In a project startup where you feel your site should look exactly same on all the browsers one common approach web designers use is writing up a reset.css file. This file sets up properties of most of the used DOM elements to a standard value.